# Every poset is embedded into a meet-semilattice

Tags: reference-request, order-theory, lattice-orders

I "discovered" a few minutes ago that every poset can be embedded into a meet-semilattice.

> Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a poset. Then it is embedded into the meet-semilattice generated by sets $\{ x \in \mathfrak{A} \mid x \le a \}$ where $a$ ranges through $\mathfrak{A}$.

I'm sure I am not the first person who discovered this. Which book could you suggest to read about such things?

Comment: This is a special case of the Yoneda embedding, which you can read about in any category theory textbook.

Comment: @ZhenLin why don't you post this as an answer.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Probably really stupid, but to the moment, I don't understand how is this related with Yoneda embedding (I am yet a beginner with CT). Does Yoneda embedding produce a semilattice (the same as mine), lattice, or whatever in this particular case?

Comment: Section 3.4 of Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics Vol 1 might be helpful. It focusses on finite posets, but gives some nicer results.  I believe your observation is implicit in that section.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: @JD It isn't an answer – just a remark. The question deserves an answer phrased in purely order-theoretic terms.

Comment: I've found that every poset can be embedded into a completely distributive lattice: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_distributive_lattice

Answer (score 4):

This result is mentioned for example as theorem 1.1 in [chapter 1](http://math.hawaii.edu/~jb/math618/os1uh.pdf) of [J.B. Nation](http://math.hawaii.edu/~jb/)'s "Revised Notes on Lattice Theory". See also theorem 2.2 in [chapter 2](http://math.hawaii.edu/~jb/math618/os2uh.pdf). One advantage of Nation's text is that it is freely available.

Answer (score 1):

Simply searching for [every poset embedded](http://books.google.com/books?q=every+poset+embedded) in Google Books returns some reasonably looking references. (Of course, you can try some other similar search queries.)

For example [Theorem 1.11](http://books.google.com/books?id=NZN8aum26LgC&pg=PA14) in the book Steven Roman: *Lattices and Ordered Sets* uses precisely the embedding you suggested to show that every poset $P$ can be order embedded in a powerset $\mathscr P(P)$.