# Every well-ordering is isomorphic to the set of all lesser ordinals under ordinal comparison

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals, motivation, well-orders

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) states that

> Every well-ordered set (S,<) is order isomorphic to the set of ordinals less than one specific ordinal number [the order type of (S,<)] under their natural ordering.

I've been trying to find proofs on the Internet of this theorem at an appropriate level of rigor, but am entirely at a loss.

The best motivation I've found for defining von Neumann ordinals as the set of all lesser ordinals is that every well-ordering is order isomorphic to the set of all lesser ordinals under the ordinal comparison operation.   Since I'm trying to use this theorem as a way to motivate *defining* ordinals, all I'd like to use in the proof is a supposition that ordinals are canonical representatives of order types, and not worry about how they're concretely defined.

I'm supposing that I've already proven that ordinal comparison is a well-ordering. How might I go about this proof? (Can I even do it without the von Neumann definition?) Thanks!

**Clarification:** My goal is not to show that every well-ordering is isomorphic to an ordinal. It is to show that every well-ordering is *already* isomorphic to a set of canonical representations of all lesser order types under ordinal comparison, so we might as well *define* ordinals as sets of all lesser ordinals, which is the von Neumann construction.

Comment: Seems like a classic induction proof, no?

Comment: Dont you just want to show that every WO is isomorphic to an ordinal number ?

Comment: Have you tried transfinite induction? For that you need to deal with a base case, successor ordinals, and limit ordinals. I am not saying I have a full proof, but I think this is sufficient.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus my goal is not to show that every WO is isomorphic to an ordinal. It is to *define* ordinals as sets of all lesser ordinals, *based on the fact* that every well-ordering is *already* isomorphic to the set of all lesser ordinals, so we might as well define it that way.

Comment: You cannot have that "that every well-ordering is already isomorphic to the set of all lesser ordinals" without having a definition of ordinal numbers.

Comment: I don't think so -- I first define ordinals non-concretely as canonical representations of order types. I prove this theorem (if possible), and *then* concretely define ordinals as the sets of all lesser representations.

Comment: There are no vague definitions in mathematics.

Comment: Canonical representations How ? It seems to me as if you want to prove a theorem about ordinals and then use that theorem as motivation for the definition of an ordinal.

Comment: My goal is to motivate the von Neumann construction. I can already have it in my head that ordinals are canonical representations of order types. Thus, I want to prove this fact about ordinals in general, but without using the von Neumann construction. I should still be able to use, for example, transfinite induction with limit/successor ordinals, since transfinite induction is valid for any definition of ordinals, not just the von Neumann construction.

Comment: @singerng "My goal is to motivate the von Neumann construction ... Thus, I want to prove this fact about ordinals in general, but without using the von Neumann construction." This seems odd - why will this help you? Exactly because this result doesn't depend on the precise von Neumann definition but is rather a general consequence of finding representatives of order-types, this *won't* help motivate or explain the von Neumann definition at all. It's vaguely relevant that the von Neumann definition makes the "embeds into" relation on ordinals particularly nice (it's just $\in$), but that's it.

Comment: If you can prove that every well ordering is isomorphic to the set of all lesser ordinals, then I’d argue that “the set of all lesser ordinals” becomes a good candidate for the canonical representation.

Comment: @singerng Ah. Well in that case, do you see how the arguments below prove that fact? (BTW if you type "@NoahSchweber" I'll see your comment faster.)

Answer (score 4):

We start by a simple observation which is true for any totally ordered set, not only for well-ordered sets.

Let $(X,\le)$ be a linearly ordered set. We will use the notation $X_a=\{x\in X; x<a\}$ pre $a\in X$. Notice that these sets are *initial segments* of $X$.

**Observation.** Let $(X,\le)$ be a linearly ordered set and let $X'=\{X_a; a\in X\}$. Then the function $f\colon X\to{X'}$ defined as
$$f(a)=X_a$$
is an isomorphism between the ordered sets $(X,\le)$ and $(X',\subseteq)$.

*Proof.* We can see immediately that $f$ is surjective. If $a<b$ then $a\in X_b$ and $a\notin X_a$, so $f(a)=X_a\ne X_b=f(b)$. The case $b<a$ is symmetric. So it is also injective.

The map $f$ is monotone: If $a \le b$ then $f(a)=\{x\in X; x<a\} \subseteq \{x\in X; x<b\}=f(b)$. (It suffices to notice that 
$x<a$ and $a\le b$ implies $x<b$ by transitivity.)

To see that also $f^{-1}$ is monotone, we notice that $X_a\subseteq X_b$ implies $a\le b$. (If we had $a>b$, then $b\in X_a\setminus X_b$, which contradicts $X_a\subseteq X_b$.) $\hspace{1cm}\square$

**Side remark.** Notice that we have used linearity of $\le$ in the above proof. The version of the above observation with $\{x\in X; x\le a\}$ instead of $X_a$ is true also for partially ordered sets and it implies that every partially ordered set is isomorphic to some system of sets ordered by inclusion (in fact, to a subset of $(\mathcal P(X),\subseteq)$.) See, for example, [Theorem 1.11](https://books.google.com/books?id=NZN8aum26LgC&pg=PA14) in S. Roman: *Lattices and Ordered Sets* or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181377/every-poset-is-embedded-into-a-meet-semilattice).

**How does this relate to ordinals?** We can view ordinals as representatives or order types of well-ordered sets. (At least if we approach them in the *naive* rather than *axiomatic* way.) We can define inequality between ordinals via *initial embeddings* of the corresponding well-ordered sets. (I.e., ordinal type of $(A,\le)$ is less or equal to ordinal type of $(B,\preceq)$ iff $A$ is isomorphic to an initial segment of $B$. This seems to be [the natural way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512255/what-is-a-good-argument-that-for-well-ordered-subsets-it-is-more-reasonable-to-t) how to compare ordinals/well-ordered sets.)

So the above lemma shows that a well-ordered set $X$ is isomorphic to the set of *proper* initial segments of $X$. Ordinal types of these initial segments are precisely the ordinals lesser than the ordinal type of $X$.

Answer (score 3):

You mention that you want an argument that doesn't invoke the specific nature of ordinals. This is in fact something we can do - specifically, we can show that the stated result holds whenever we have a reasonable notion of "representatives" of well-orderings. This is the argument below:

---

Suppose I have a class of representatives for all well-orderings - that is, I have a way to assign to each well-ordering $W$ a well-ordering $REP(W)$ such that the following are equivalent:

- $W_0$ and $W_1$ are order-isomorphic.
- $REP(W_0)=REP(W_1)$. *That's literally "$=$," not just "$\cong$."*

(So the $REP(W)$s really do represent isomorphism types of well-orderings.) Call these $REP(W)$s **representative well-orders**.

Now there are two important things to note here:

- There is a natural relation $\trianglelefteq$ on the class of representative well-orders: $A\trianglelefteq B$ iff there is an order-preserving injection of $A$ into $B$. This is clearly transitive and reflexive, and it can be shown that it is in fact a (class) well-ordering on the class of representative well-orders. **NOTE: this is the only place where transfinite induction is used here.**

*In the particular case of the von Neumann ordinals, "$\alpha\trianglelefteq\beta$" is equivalent to "$\alpha\in\beta$," so the von Neumann approach has the advantage of making "$\trianglelefteq$" particularly nice to define.*

- Given a well-ordering $W$, not only is there the associated representative $REP(W)$, but there is *also* a function $F_W$ from $W$ to the class of representative well-orders: given $w\in W$, let $$F_W(w)=REP(W\upharpoonright w)$$ (where $W\upharpoonright w$ is the sub-well-order of $W$ consisting of elements $<_Ww$), and remember that by definition of $REP$ the orderings $F_W(w)$ and $W\upharpoonright w$ are order-isomorphic.

The map $F_W$ has a few nice properties; the following is key:

> If $u\le_Wv$ then $F_W(u)\trianglelefteq F_W(v)$.

To prove this, note that we have a few functions here:

- There is the inclusion map $j$ from $W\upharpoonright u$ to $W\upharpoonright v$ - this is order-preserving.
- There are order-isomorphisms $i_u: W\upharpoonright u\rightarrow F_W(u)$ and $i_v: W\upharpoonright v\rightarrow F_W(v)$ giving representatives for  the initial segments of $W$ associated to $u$ and $v$, respectively.

---

Alright, so what? Let's remember our goal:

> For every well-ordering $W$, $W$ is isomorphic to the set $\{REP(W\upharpoonright w): w\in W\}$ ordered by $\trianglelefteq$.

The obvious candidate isomorphism is the map sending $w$ to $REP(W\upharpoonright w)$; we just need to show that this *is* an isomorphism.

We want, then, an order-preserving injection $C$ (for **c**omparison) from $F_W(u)$ to $F_W(v)$, and we can get this as follows: $$C(x)=i_v(j(i_u^{-1}(x))).$$ That is:

- We take some $x$ in $F_W(u)$.
- Where do we send it? Well, first we convert it to an element of $W\upharpoonright u$, by pulling back along $i_u$. Remember that $i_u$ is a bijection, so this is something we can do.
- OK, now we have an element of $W\upharpoonright u$ and we want to put it into $F_W(v)$. There's an obvious way to do this: first, throw it over to $W\upharpoonright v$ using the inclusion map $j$, and then bump that into $F_W(v)$ via the isomorphism $i_v$. So that's what we do.

It's easy to check that $C$ is in fact an order-preserving injection, the key being that each of the maps along the way - $i_u^{-1}$, $j$, and $i_v$ - was order-preserving and injective.

Comment: How do you manage to produce such a prodigious answer is such a short time ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I'm secretly twenty highly-caffeinated squirrels in a person suit.

Answer (score 2):

This probably doesn't answer OP question, (as I don't know what he really wants), but I copied it from some rough notes of mine.

We must use the axiom of replacement. Consider the formula

$$\varphi(x, \beta) \equiv \beta \ \mbox{is an ordinal} \wedge L_x \cong (\beta,<).$$

$\varphi$ is a function since if $(\beta,<) \cong (\gamma,<)$, where $\beta$ and
$\gamma$ are ordinals then $\beta=\gamma$.
Then by the axiom of replacement there is a set $X$ such that $$X= \{ \beta \ | \ (\exists x \in L) \ \varphi(x, \beta) \}.$$ The set $X$ is a set of ordinals, furthermore $X$ is transitive, thus $X$ is an ordinal let $X=\alpha$.
Also the domain of $\varphi$ is an initial segment of $L$.
I claim that $\operatorname{dom} \varphi = L$ since otherwise  $\operatorname{dom} \varphi = L_x$ for some $x \in L$, and so $\alpha \cong L_x$ and thus $\alpha$ itself is in the domain of
$\varphi$.
The set $ f \subseteq \{ (x, \beta) \in \alpha \times L \ | \ L_x \cong (\beta,<) \}$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(S,<)$ be any well-ordered set, and let $Ord$ denote your class of canonical representatives (I'm not assuming the Von Neumann definition, but the hypotheses I'm using will become clear along the proof).

Then let $F(x, \alpha)$ be an abbreviation for $x \in S\land \alpha \in Ord \land S[x]\simeq \alpha$,  where $\simeq$ means "order-isomorphic" and $S[x] = \{y\in S : y<x\}$.

Then, if $F(x,\alpha), F(x, \beta)$, we get $\alpha \simeq \beta$, and so if we assume that elements of $Ord$ are pairwise non-isomorphic (which is the point of "canonical representatives"), we have $\alpha = \beta$, so $F$ is a functional relation.
(Note that I'm also assuming that elements of $Ord$ are sets, not full-isomorphism classes for instance)

By the axiom schema of replacement, the following is a set $B=\{\alpha : \exists x, F(x,\alpha) \}$, and $f= \{(x, \alpha) : F(x, \alpha)\}$ is a function from a subset of $S$ to $B$.

If we assume that $Ord$ contains representatives for each isomorphism type (which again is kind of wanted for "canonical representatives"), then this function is actually defined on $S$; and by classical properties of well-orderings, it is injective: it is an isomorphism onto its image.

Now if we let $\gamma \in Ord$ be the representative isomorphic to $S$, it is clear that $B \subset \{\alpha: \alpha \in Ord \land \alpha < \gamma \}$, where $<$ is the "can be embedded" relation on $Ord$. Let $\delta$ be the least element in $Ord$ (you've assumed that the comparison relation was a well-ordering) such that $B \subset \{\alpha: \alpha \in Ord \land \alpha < \delta \}$.

Now let $\beta \in Ord, \beta < \delta$. By minimality, there is $\lambda \in B$ such that $\beta \leq \lambda$. Consider $x$ such that $\lambda \simeq S[x]$. Then any embedding $\beta \to \lambda$ provides an embedding $\beta \to S[x]$, so an embedding $\beta \to S$ with proper image, so there is an embedding $\beta \to S$ where the image of $\beta$ is a proper initial segment of $S$ (classical property of well-orderings), and so $\beta \simeq S[y]$ for some $y\in S$: $\beta \in B$, and so $B= \{\alpha: \alpha \in Ord \land \alpha < \delta \}$ which is what you wanted to prove, since $B$ and $S$ are isomorphic.